# Xsane : black and white ICC lack or error

Tags: scanning, icc

I made a ICC color profile for my scanner I can use it in Xsane.
But if I want to scan a BW image, Xsane doesn't find a BW ICC profile.

If I use the color one as BW, Xsane claims for error because the color one is tagged `RGB`.

How to avoid this problem :

- Use the color ICC as BW, as fake?
- Or make a BW ICC profile? but how using Ubuntu?